# Retrieve a object from a list of objects in visual basic and use it to fill text/combo boxes

Tags: vb.net, object

I have a class as seen below:

```
Public Class parameters
  Public Property test As String
  Public Property test_type As String
  Public Property user_test_name As String
  Public Property meas As String
  Public Property spec As String
  ...etc
End Class
```

I make a list of objects that I import from a csv somewhere. The user_test_name's from the list gets sent to a list box:

```
For Each parameters In param
  ' MsgBox(parameters.user_test_name)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(parameters.user_test_name)
Next
```

now when the user selects something from the list i want the rest of the properties of that particular user_test_name object to populate in certain text/combo boxes in the application. Here is how I grab what is selected.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Dim selected_name As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem()
  ' MsgBox(selected_name)
  find_object_by_user_test_name(selected_name)
End Sub
```

Now i'm having difficulty finding the object with the selected_name from the list and using its properties to fill the text.combo boxes. I tried the following to no success:

```
Public Sub find_object_by_user_test_name(ByVal description)
  MsgBox(description)
  Dim matches = From parameters In param
  Where parameters.user_test_name = description
  Select parameters
  ' MsgBox(matches)
  '  MsgBox(matches.user_test_name)
  TextBox1.Text = matches.test
  TextBox2.Text = matches.test_name
  etc,,, on and on
  ' populate_area(matches)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the name (a string) to the ListBox, add your actual **INSTANCE** to it.

First, override ToString() in your class so that it displays properly in your ListBox:

```
Public Class parameters

    Public Property test As String
    Public Property test_type As String
    Public Property user_test_name As String
    Public Property meas As String
    Public Property spec As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return user_test_name
    End Function

End Class
```

Next, add each instance to the ListBox:

```
For Each parameters In param
    ListBox1.Items.Add(parameters)
Next
```

Now, the SelectedIndexChanged() event, you can cast the SelectedItem() item back to parameters and you already have everything at your disposal:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim P As parameters = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, parameters)
        ' ... do something with "P" ...
        Debug.Print(P.user_test_name & " --> " & P.test)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sidenote: If `param` is a `List(Of parameters)` then you can simply set the DataSource of your ListBox with `ListBox1.DataSource = param`.

Answer (score 1):

If the user_test_names are unique, it may be easier to use a dictionary and retrieve the objects that way.

```
Dim params As New Dictionary(Of String, parameters)

params.add(MyParameterObject.user_test_name, MyParameterObject)
```

Then

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim selected_name As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem()
    Dim selected_param as parameters = params(selected_name)



End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why would a dictionary be a better alternative to this problem?

Comment: It cuts down on complexity, you would have no need for the function that iterates over every object in the collection. Also a dictionary uses a more efficient means to retrieve the value you are looking for than a for loop would. So you would see better performance as your list of objects grows.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
Public Sub find_object_by_user_test_name(ByVal description As String)
  ' assuming param is your list of parameter objects
  For Each p In param
    If p.user_test_name = description Then
      TextBox1.Text = p.test
      TestBox2.Text = p.test_name
      ...
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

A few notes about your code. First, you can't allow two objects to have the same `user_test_name`. Second, you can't use `parameters` as a variable name if you already have a class called `parameters` in your current namespace (which you do).

Comment: I also agree with Ceres, a dictionary would serve you better here. It is less code and will exhibit better performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution than any of these--just do the following:

Dim i as Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex

Then you can use i as an index to your original list of objects.